# Getting database for Echoprint Api using Python getting error

Tags: solr, audio-fingerprinting, musicbrainz, tokyo-tyrant

i am trying to get started with Echoprint api .just installed Echoprint server and run it then i run a command for getting database of Echoprint api

```
ritesh@L901134:~/echoprint/util$ python fastingest.py -b /home/ritesh/Downloads/echoprint-dump.json
```

and the error logs i am getting is

```
1/1 /home/ritesh/Downloads/echoprint-dump.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fastingest.py", line 62, in <module>
    codes, bigeval = parse_json_dump(f)
  File "fastingest.py", line 14, in parse_json_dump
    codes = json.load(open(jfile))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 278, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

can any one please tell why i am facing this error and how to remove it so that i can get complete database ??

Comment: Is the DB download complete? No issues with file truncation at 2 GB? The error message basically says "This is no valid json". I remember downloading the DB once and it was quite big.

Comment: It looks like you json file is corrupted. Check if there is a closing ] in the end of this archive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command:"
`python splitdata.py .../big.json` to split file in more mini.json. In this case you will can ingest json's and find which file is broken. 
for example :
after splitting will have:
big-1.json
big-2.json
big-3.json - broken 
big-4.json
big-5.json

continue to insert 1,2,4,5 - and than try to split again big-3.json ... infinit than, you will find broken file, which you can repair manually.